# Need assistance regarding Objective-c properties concept

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am reading [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) for understanding property instance variable but bit confused

From Apple Doc:

> Most Properties Are Backed by Instance Variables By default, a
>   readwrite property will be backed by an instance variable, which will
>   again be synthesized automatically by the compiler.
>
> An instance variable is a variable that exists and holds its value for
>   the life of the object. The memory used for instance variables is
>   allocated when the object is first created (through alloc), and freed
>   when the object is deallocated.
>
> Unless you specify otherwise, the synthesized instance variable has
>   the same name as the property, but with an underscore prefix. For a
>   property called firstName, for example, the synthesized instance
>   variable will be called _firstName.
>
> ***Although it’s best practice for an object to access its own properties
>   using accessor methods or dot syntax, it’s possible to access the
>   instance variable directly from any of the instance methods in a class
>   implementation. The underscore prefix makes it clear that you’re
>   accessing an instance variable rather than, for example, a local
>   variable:***

If using accessor methods or dot syntax is best practice then why user _ivarPropertyName?

Why use ivar for presenting properties? what are its benefits? when apple says "using accessor methods or dot syntax is best practice"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@property` declares the existence of a property (describing its interface), but doesn't specify the implementation of that property. But properties need to store their contents *somewhere*. By default, the compiler synthesizes an *ivar* for that (and matching setters and getters). So normally you can ignore the existence of the *ivar* and just use *dot syntax*.

I follow Apple's advice and try to avoid using *ivars* directly. But somtimes you want to access a property without invoking its getter. The most common exception in my code is lazily-initialized read-only properties:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property ( nonatomic, readonly ) id someProperty ;
@end

@implementation MyObject
@synthesize someProperty = _someProperty ; // required; compiler will not auto-synthesize ivars for readonly properties

-(id)someProperty
{
    if ( !_someProperty )
    {
        _someProperty = ... create property here
    }

    return _someProperty ;
}

@end
```

Also, you may not want to invoke the getter for a property in your `-dealloc` method... for example, a timer property. To avoid creating a timer in `-dealloc`, access the ivar directly:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [ _myTimer invalidate ] ; // don't use self.myTimer here, that would create a timer even though we're going away...
}
```

There are probably more use cases. For most properties you don't even need to use the ivar, just use `<value> = self.property` and `self.property = <new value>`.

**edit:**

Also, there will be some additional overhead for accessing the property via message dispatch (using *dot-accessor syntax* or the getter) vs directly accessing the *ivar*, but it will make no difference in almost all cases.