# Objective-C is @synthesize required or optional?

Tags: ios, objective-c

sorry I'm a newbie iOS developer, recently I've briefly heard that @synthesize is now @synthesize in a certain version of Xcode and that the compiler will auto synthesize and properties and assign _ to private variables.

I've tested this:

with out @synthesize, you can access properties and private field using

```
self.property_name = something;
_property_name = something; //(used in getter and setters)
```

with @synthesize property_name, you can access properties and private field using

```
self.property_name = something;
property_name = something;
```

My question is do we really need @synthesize anymore? or there is a bigger story I'm missing?

Comment: the latest version of the compiler will put in the `@synthesize` for you if you leave it out in most cases. I just wrote about properties here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493882/need-assistance-regarding-objective-c-properties-concept/15494036#15494036

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666008/automatically-synthesized-properties-in-xcode-4-4

Comment: Depends on the phase of the moon, and, more to the point, which version of Xcode you're using.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No we don't need to do that as of Xcode 4.4, which added a feature called Default Synthesis Of Properties.

Simply put, it generates this automatically:

```
@synthesize name = _name;
```

Comment: Caveat:  If you override all of the auto-generated methods, this line will not be auto-generated (but you can still write it yourself to get the variable).  Also, properties defined in protocols will not be auto-synthesized (instead you will get a compiler warning).  Lastly, subclasses of `NSManagedObject` also have this behavior disabled because it is largely undesired.

Comment: This answer is *too* simply put. For the details read this post: [Automatic Property Synthesis With Xcode 4.4](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html)

Comment: Another Caveat: If you have declared properties in a protocol, they will need synthesizing.

Comment: so you only need/have to use it when you wanna rename a property declared in header.

Answer (score -3):

Unless you've been using it like I have, then you still need it, as far as I can tell:

in .h:

```
@property int32_t FwdID;
```

in .m:

```
@synthesize FwdID;
```

usage inside class:

```
FwdID = 0;
```

From what I can tell, if you want the default to work for you, you'll have to type _FwdID = 0; in the code, which just looks ugly to me.

So if you are like me (breaking all the standard coding conventions I assume), you'll still need to use synthesize.

Comment: You should access the properties via their getters and setters `[self setFwdID:0];`, otherwise use a real instance variable and not a property.