# How do I synthesize Objective-C string?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to synthesize two strings in Objective C so the setter/getter is automatically created.

In my implementation:

```
#import "Song.h"

@implementation Song

@synthesize song, track;

@end
```

In my interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Song : NSObject

@property string song, track;

@end
```

The error I am getting in my interface file is "Unknown type name string".

The error I am getting in my implementation file is "Expected a property name in @synthesize".

I am unsure what to do because I did this for int and it works.

Comment: `@property NSString *song, *track;`

Comment: Given your apparent newness to Objective-C, may I suggest you take some time to work with some good Objective-C tutorials or a good book. Learn the basics first. It will save you a lot of time later.

Comment: [Good resources for learning ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374660)

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems in your code:

- Cocoa does not have a type called `string`, you need to use `NSString` instead
- [As of Xcode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15606151/335858) you do not need to use `@synthesize`.

Here is how:

```
@interface Song : NSObject
// Below I am using copy to avoid referencing potentially mutable strings.
// You may or may not want to use this approach.
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *song;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *track;

@end
```

Comment: @matsoftware you don't need either. `strong`, `readwrite` and `atomic` are the default.

Answer (score 3):

Synthesizing is done automatically in XCode 4.4 and later.

Your actual issue, though, is the declaration of the string properties.

in your header try

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *song;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *track;
```

You can then reference those properties using

```
self.song
```

or access the property directly using

```
_song
```

Please note the second method is NOT recommended unless you're accessing the instance of the property *within the setter or getter*

The reason why it worked for `int` is because `int` is a primitive (and objective-c is a superset of C).  An [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) is an [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSObject) in Objective-C and you must hold a strong or weak reference to it (you must point to it).  You can read Apple's [reference  on encapsulating data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) for more information on properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *song;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *track;
```

Comment: NSString properties (or any of the classes with mutable/immutable types) should really use `copy` instead of `strong`.

Answer (score 0):

In implementation:

```
#import "Song.h"

@implementation Song

@synthesize song, track;

@end
```

In interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Song : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *song;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *track;

@end
```